# Deleted row in oracle database is retrieved through JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate

I had deleted one row from one of the table of oracle database still that row is retrieved through `JdbcTemplate`.

I had deleted that row using following command

```sql
delete from user where RAD_ID="demo";
```

Still that row is retrieved through `JdbcTemplate` in my Java code. I am kind of shocked by this scenario.

Comment: Did you commit after the delete? (Clearly, the answer is 'no', unless something is cacheing the data higher up the stack... *8-) Are you sure you're connected to the same DB and schema?

Comment: Yes I did commit

Comment: sorry sorry that commit was not  successful because of some reason

Comment: Can you find that row if you search for it with a DB client ? (Oracle SQL developer or whatever)

Comment: Now that row is not retrieved in java code. Thank you

Comment: I cant find that row in sql developer

Comment: I  had tried to close the connection in sql developer then pop came in sql developer asking do you want to commit the changes. I clicked on yes and bingo that row is deleted now

Answer (score 2):

You are running SQL statements in different [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). You need to either commit the first transaction opened for `DELETE` statement or reuse the first transaction for `SELECT` statement. Depending on you [transaction isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) you may observe stale data reads in `SELECT`.